# Check if an element loaded via partial view exists using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm working on an ASP.net mvc project and loading some html using a partial view. I want to check if the ***info-cache*** element is available once it's been loaded to the main page but my script doesn't seem to work.
I can definitely see the partial view content has loaded onto the page but the script doesn't seem to be firing as I cannot see the 'loaded' message writing to my console.
Any idea where I've gone wrong?
Many thanks.

```
<!-- partial view content -->
<div class="info-display">
   <input class="info-cache" type="hidden">
   <a href="#" class="info-update">Update</a>
</div>

//Script
$('body').on('load', '.info-cache', function () {
   console.log('loaded');
});
```

Comment: you just want to check, or trap an event when the class appears?

Comment: you could have problem if already in browser cache, the event is not seen in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to trap if something exits you could use setInterval to repeat an action

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
  if ($("input.info-cache").length) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log('loaded');
  }
}, 250);//you could adjust the lapse for the next repeat
```

Comment: Thanks @Frenchy - this seems to have done the job for me! I'm not sure why my implementation didn't work as I've used the same for click event which is on the 'info-update' link in the same partial view. I've used $('body').on('click', '.info-update', fetchInfo);